# Bounce Back not showing as Failed in Mailing Statistics

Tags: 2011, outbound-email, tracking

I am working on configuring Outbound Email for a client and I have run into a problem with handling bounced emails. The email comes into the POP3 box and is processed by the Tridion Bounce processor. I even get a notification email from Tridion once this is done. The problem I have is that the statistics for the mailing do not update showing that there was a failed message. The contact however is labeled as having persistent email problems so that they will no longer receive emails.

I have tried hitting refresh statistics multiple times and have seen no change. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to resolve it? I am using Tridion 2011 SP1. I am new to Outbound Email and also not familiar with what in the email it uses to distinguish individual email for tracking failures in mailings. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably be happening as the bounce has no tracked link, and thus cannot be tied to a specific Mailing and Contact.  If you do make use of tracked links then it is likely the email server which generated the bounce has not responded with the original message (or altered it in such a way it is no longer recognizable).  If you place the Outbound E-mail logging in trace or debug mode you should be able to see the source of the email, along with details as to how the Bounce Processor will categorize the bounce.

Comment: Absolutely. The clue is in the fact that the Contact did get updated -- so the e-mail *was* recognized as a bounce and the Contact was updated based on the e-mail address. But the Mailing could not be identified due to the missing tracked link.

Comment: Thanks for the insight here. I was unaware that the tracked links were what Tridion uses to make that association between an email and the mailing it was sent from.